# How do i convert 0x00000001AE76E3BF timestamp?

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have the following timestamp '0x00000001B5E789D1' or '0x00000001AE76E3BF' in a file i have received and i'm supposed to process it in sql but i don't know how to convert it. Can you please help me with the date format?

Thanks

Comment: So what value is `0x00000001B5E789D1` supposed to be? That doesn't even look remotely like a timestamp.

Comment: I have just received an excel with the information, i've searched what is supposed to be on google but i can't find it. I'm using microsoft server manangement studio. The excel i have received is part of a test on an interview so maybe they're trying to figure out if i can ask for help because damn, i have no idea how to find it.